# WebView not rendering content properly in Android L

Tags: android, webkit, android-webview, android-scrollview, android-5.0-lollipop

I am facing problem loading html content in Android L (preview) WebView. Sometimes when html content loads, it does not show up in WebView. I have to tap in WebView or somewhere inside the screen then it shows up the content. There is no problem with WebView in Android KitKat and lower versions. It happens only with Android L WebView. Please note that I have WebView inside ScrollView. This is my primary requirement as there can be multiple WebViews inside the scrollable view.

Comment: If I disable hardware acceleration in app manifest, everything works fine. But I don't want to disable it as it improves app's performance. Is there any solution for the problem?